# How to insert ascending numbers in a Red Black Tree

Tags: red-black-tree

Can someone show me a step by step tutorial on how to insert numbers 1-10 in a Red-black tree?

I already tried doing so but I seem to be failing

*by insert I mean adding 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in an initially empty rbt. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by " insert numbers 1-10 in a Red-black tree":

- If you mean a legal tree obtained from these values, you can build a red-black tree from an ordered vector in linear time.
- If you mean a visualization of 10 insert operations, you can try [here](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/RedBlack.html).

[image: Drawn with the help of the link mentioned here]

- For a general description of the insert operation, and detailed examples for various cases, see ["Introduction To Algorithms"](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms).

Comment: Very nice of you to provide the animation link, I have added the image after playing with the animation given in the link provided in your answer. And,+1. :)

Comment: Au contraire! Very nice of you to add the final result. Thanks!